# Promo Video not visible on Google Play, but works on Android Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have added "Promo Video" to my app on Google Play. It is placed on youtube, it is between 30s and 2min and it plays correctly on Google Play accessed from Android device. But when I go to app web page on play.google.com (on my laptop, using any browser), I can't see it there. Note that screenshots appears correctly, and video has been added to app over 48h ago.

I have already searched a lot of HELP articles and google and didn't find any similar issue or solution.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same problem. The solution was to use the full YouTube video link as explained here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870

- Use the full YouTube video link instead of a shortened link.

  - Use: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yourvideoid`
  - Don't use: `https://youtu.be/yourvideoid`

Comment: My game not show promote in play store app. But still showing in web. Already follow every rule. Could you help me

Comment: I've uploaded the promo video and its reflecting in the store when opened in chrome using desktop/laptop but when I open play store app in mobile/tab it's now showing there, any idea?

Comment: it does not change anything on my side

Comment: My problem was that I disallowed Embedding on my video, which is a requirement in the guidelines https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1078870

Comment: Have you guys solved this ? I have the same problem, working on web doesnt show in android play store :)

Comment: I've done the answer above, still it couldn't be found in both web/mobile